# How to determine if a set is connected?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I am given that $A \setminus B$ is equal to the values of $A$ that are not found in $B$. Then I am given a bunch of different sets. My task is to determine if these sets are connected.

Now, I get the principle of connected domains and that each pair of points should be possible to join through a smooth curve in the domain. However, I have no idea on how I am supposed to calculate if a set is connected or not. Is it trial and error for different values? How do I interpret the values I get?

For example, this is one of the sets I am given
$$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z): z=4x+7y+7\}$$

How should approach this problem?

Comment: You should try to figure out what the set $\{(x,y,z): z=4x+7y+7\}$ looks like, and then think about whether $\Bbb R^3$ remains connected after you remove that set, or whether the set divides $\Bbb R^3$ into separate parts.

Comment: The set you're leaving out is a plane. What's your intuition about space minus a plane? Is it one piece or more?

Comment: @Arthur Is it correct that it will split R^3 into two halfs? Is that the correct approach?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma So the correct way to intuitively think about it is placing the shape of **B** into the set of **A** and see if it splits up the domain into multiple parts?

Comment: @PhyCoMath Yes, that's right. At least intuitively. Now you have a much better idea of what you're trying to prove. You have an upper half and a lower half, and you need to prove that you can't get from one to the other without crossing the border (technically connecting points in the domain through continuous curves is the definition of _path-connectedness_, which is similar to connectedness but not entirely equivalent). And generally, placing $B$ into $A$ and see what the rest of $A$ looks like is a good way to approach it visually.

Comment: @Arthur Very well explained intuitively. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z): z=4x+7y+7\} = \{(x,y,z): z>4x+7y+7\} \cup \{(x,y,z): z<4x+7y+7\}$$

so your space can be written as a union of two nonempty disjoint sets which are both open in $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{(x,y,z): z=4x+7y+7\}$.

Conclude that it is not connected.

Comment: Is this valid for all cases?

Comment: @PhyCoMath Of course not, $[0,2] = [0,1] \cup \langle 1, 2]$ but those two sets are not both open in $[0,2]$. If a set is disconnected though, then such a separation must exist.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{(x,y,z): z=4x+7y+7\}$ and $M:= \mathbb R^3 \setminus P$.

Then $(0,0,0), (1,1,1) \in M$. Now show that there is no continuous mapping $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^3$ with

$f(0)=(0,0,0), f(1)=(1,1,1)$ and $f([0,1]) \subseteq M$.

Comment: As I've said, I get the meaning of a connected domain. It's the intuitive approach to solving the problem that I struggle with.